# Use a function or Expression to replace the "new {x.ID,x.Name}" part

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I may have function calls like this :

```
foo(**new {x.ID,x.Name}**);
```

and **LINQ**:

```
(IQueryable<SomeTableName>).where(x=>x.ID>1).select(x=>**new {x.ID,x.Name}**);
```

Is it possible to replace the `"new {x.ID,x.Name}"` part with a function, expression or variable, so I can change from time to time, in only 1 place?
Thank you.

I know I can make an Expression, which be used inside LINQ only

```
public static Func<SomeTableName, Object> Select_RS_Food = x => new { x.ID,x.Name };
```

but I also want to use for normal anonymous object creating. Like:

```
foo(CreateMyObject(x));
```

**Update**

Current:

```
return new { myTable.ID, myTable.Name};
//And
db.SomeTable.Select (x=> new { myTable.ID, myTable.Name));
```

Expect:

```
return SomeMagicCode;
//And
db.SomeTable.Select (x=> SomeMagicCode);
```

Comment: Anonymous types can't be returned across method signatures or in explicit generics (the "expression" approach shown yields a non-typed result) in a typed fashion. Perhaps use a non-anonymous type here?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we can use non-anonymous type. But I wonder is it possible to generalize that part, just like we put some code into a function and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a helper class like this to allow you to specify only some of the generic type parameters when creating a `Func<T, R>`:

```
public static class Funk<T>
{
    public static Func<T, R> Make<R>(Func<T, R> func)
    {
        return func;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var selector = Funk<SomeTableName>.Make(x => new {x.ID, x.Name});
var result = db.SomeTable.Where(x => x.ID>1).Select(selector);
```

This takes advantage of type inference to determine the return type, so you only have to define the input type (`SomeTableName`). The `var` keyword makes the `selector` variable implicitly typed, you won't have to specify `Func<SomeTableName, _AnonymousType1_>`. You can now reuse `selector` in multiple queries.

You will not be able to save this as property or field of a class, however, because implicit typing is not supported in type members. If you want to be able to reuse this selection function, you must use a named type or perhaps `dynamic`—but I wouldn't expect this to work with any current ORM.

For the other lambda expressions (`x => x.ID == 1` and `x => x.ID > 1`), there are no anonymous types involved so you can simply do this:

```
public static Func<SomeTableName, bool> IDEquals1 = x => x.ID == 1;
public static Func<SomeTableName, bool> IDGreaterThan1 = x => x.ID == 1;
```

But by the way, if your using an ORM like entity framework, you probably need to use an `Expression` instead. Maybe something kind of like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> IDEquals1 = x => x.ID == 1;
```

Or even this:

```
public interface IHasID 
{
    int ID { get; }
}

public SomeTableName : IHasID { ... }

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> IDEquals1<T>() where T : IHasID
{
     return x => x.ID == 1;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the selector part. I am using LINQ to get results like: 'db.SomeTable.Single(x=>x.ID==1)' and 'db.SomeTable.Where(x=>x.ID>1)'  And I need to choose part of the columns and return anonymous type.  The selector can only be used after '.Where'. Is there any possibility we can have a thing to be used for both?

Comment: @Yiping In that case you don't need any anonymous types, so this is much more simple. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g I understand the Expression.Sorry I may not articulate well, but precisely I want to study the anonymous type creating, by abstract "the new { myTable.ID, myTable.Name};". Please see my update